# Does Saver not support string variables?

Tags: tensorflow

It appears that the builtin checkpointing tools do not support saving `string` variables? For example this fails:

```
var = tf.Variable('hello world')
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

If so is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String support was added to (the ops used in) [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) earlier this month, [in this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/107853df74593ee0d88e9634b4fc21431d9404a7). This support is not available in the current (0.6.0) release, but it will appear in the next release. If you want to use it in the meantime, you should [install TensorFlow from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources).